# split dataframe by row, do separate operations, join again

Tags: r

I would like to split my dataset "test" by rows (split_var) to "test1" and "test2" and do separate operations to x. Then I would like to join it again but I want to make sure that it has still the same order, since test is also a subset (by columns) of another dataframe (lets say initial_test). Do I need to create a join index like in STATA?

```
test = data.frame(a = 1:10,
                  b= 11:20,
                  filter_var =c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0))

#initial_test = cbind(test, some_other_dataset)




test1 = test %>% 
  filter(filter_var==1)

test2 = test %>% 
  filter(filter_var==0)

test1 = test1 %>% 
  mutate(x = b + 1 )

test2 = test2 %>% 
  mutate(x = b + 10 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` and `unsplit`. For this, it's better to use letters for the split variable to avoid illegal names.

This method splits your data frame into a list on which elements you can do operations separately.

```
test.list <- split(test, test$filter_var)

## doing operations
test.list$A <- transform(test.list$A, x=b + 1)
test.list$B <- transform(test.list$B, x=b + 10)
```

For `unsplit` we take the same split variable.

```
test <- unsplit(test.list, test$filter_var)
test
#     a  b filter_var  x
# 1   1 11          A 12
# 2   2 12          B 22
# 3   3 13          A 14
# 4   4 14          B 24
# 5   5 15          A 16
# 6   6 16          B 26
# 7   7 17          A 18
# 8   8 18          B 28
# 9   9 19          A 20
# 10 10 20          B 30
```

**Note:** Be cautious with the names of the added variables. If you'd call the variable of the second list, say, `y`, `unsplit` merges both into the same columns without an error, although the names are actually different:

```
test.list$B <- transform(test.list$B, y=b + 10)
test <- unsplit(test.list, test$filter_var)
test
#     a  b filter_var  x
# 1   1 11          A 12
# 2   2 12          B 22
# 3   3 13          A 14
# 4   4 14          B 24
# 5   5 15          A 16
# 6   6 16          B 26
# 7   7 17          A 18
# 8   8 18          B 28
# 9   9 19          A 20
# 10 10 20          B 30
```

In this case it might be safer to use `merge` to "unsplit".

```
merge(test.list$A, test.list$B, all=TRUE)
#     a  b filter_var  x  y
# 1   1 11          A 12 NA
# 2   2 12          B NA 22
# 3   3 13          A 14 NA
# 4   4 14          B NA 24
# 5   5 15          A 16 NA
# 6   6 16          B NA 26
# 7   7 17          A 18 NA
# 8   8 18          B NA 28
# 9   9 19          A 20 NA
# 10 10 20          B NA 30
```

---

*Data:*

```
test <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20, filter_var=c("A", "B"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to do this using your example is to not split `test` at all, but create the new variable using an `ifelse`:

```r
test %>% mutate(x = ifelse(filter_var == 1, b + 1, b + 10))
#>     a  b filter_var  x
#> 1   1 11          1 12
#> 2   2 12          0 22
#> 3   3 13          1 14
#> 4   4 14          0 24
#> 5   5 15          1 16
#> 6   6 16          0 26
#> 7   7 17          1 18
#> 8   8 18          0 28
#> 9   9 19          1 20
#> 10 10 20          0 30
```

Comment: This might be elegant, but I'm not sure how that answers the question.

Comment: @jay.sf It's an attempt to open the OP to an alternative approach to the problem that is more efficient and may be simpler. Of course it depends on the use case. We see a lot of x-y problems on SO as you know: If someone asks "Can someone show me the best way to eat soup with a fork?", then "use a spoon instead" may not be directly answering the question, but it is a better approach to the overall problem of eating soup than "bend the fork into a spoon shape" which technically does answer the question.

Comment: Good point, OP still doesn't know how to split and unsplit, though.

Comment: Yes, that's true @jay.sf +1 for a clear expostion from you!